# Ways to Improve generic Dictionary performance

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictinary<int, int>` which populated with ~5Mio records.

While the performance is reasonably good considering the volume of data I'm looking to improve it. I don't care about data population my main concern is data retrieval.

First thing I'd done - I changed value type from `decimal` to `int` which got me twice better performance.

Then I tried trading 'genericness' for speed by passing non-generic IntComparer into Dictionary's ctor as follows:

```
public class IntegerComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
    {
        public bool Equals(int x, int y)
        {
            return x == y;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int obj)
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

but to no avail, performance got degraded by 20%. SortedDictionary slowed things down by 10 times (didn't have much hope on it though). Wonder what can be done for improving the performance if any?

here's a synthetic test just for measuring performance:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                d.Add(i, i + 5);
            }



        var r = new Random();

        var s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var r0 = Enumerable.Range(1, 255).Select(t => r.Next(5000000));
            var values = r0.Select(t => d[t]).ToList();
        }

        s.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

Comment: Why do you exptect that you get better results with a custom comparer than with the default comparer with `int`? Maybe you are optimizing the wrong thing, how do you access the dictionary and why? What does it store? Do you have enough memory?

Comment: If you really want to you can achieve a lot better performance by writing your own hash table. The built-in Dictionary has a few overheads in it that are not strictly needed. When I last did this I think I got like 5x speedup doing that. This is a lot of testing and tuning work. On the other hand I had a small data set. Yours does not fit into the CPU cache so the memory accesses might dwarf everything else.

Comment: @usr you did this more than once? ... ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig these were specialized hash tables for special occasions. Not totally reusable.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter what a question - if I'd know how to do it I probably won't post here, at least in a form of a question! I put up a sampe code.

Comment: Your benchmark tests a lot of unrelated stuff such as Random and LINQ stuff. Get rid of all of that to obtain a valid measurement. Also, 100k lookups is far too small to achieve a noise-free result. Dictionary does like 10M operations per second. Did you use Release mode without debugger?

Comment: @GameAlchemist could you elaborate more? What are you suggesting to replace dict[key] with?

Comment: @usr I know that just get be better figures assuming the rest is constant! I did indeed.

Comment: @Dmitry What do your integer keys represent? Can they also represent an index in an array? Or are they extremely high values?

Comment: @Dmitry: you don't measure dictionary performance but how long it takes to loop 100000*255 elements and adding them to 100000 lists which also have to be resized constantly. So this is completely unrelated.

Comment: If you're not willing to perform a clean benchmark you will not achieve the results you are looking for.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead They are almost sequential numbers with some gaps,  I can probably make them starting from 0, but would it make sense??

Comment: @GameAlchemist no need to say just code it up using the performance test I published.

Comment: What's the highest index you can expect to see?

Comment: @GameAlchemist List<int> indeed gavem me another 50% of improvement!

Comment: @GameAlchemist don't give up so easy! What you said does make sense.

Comment: @James Barrass it's about 5Mio if I start from 0. And I think I've got some pretty good results using List<int> or Array as per gamealchemist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments point out your test is seriously flawed...

If the highest index you will see is 5,000,0000 then an array will be the most performant option. I've tried to quickly rewrite your test to try an eliminate some of the error. There will probably be mistakes, writing accurate benchmarks is hard.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loopLength = 100000000;

        var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            d.Add(i, i + 5);
        }
        var ignore = d[7];

        var a = new int[5000000];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            a[i] = i + 5;
        }
        ignore = a[7];

        var s = new Stopwatch();
        var x = 1;
        s.Start();

        for (var i = 0; i < loopLength; i++)
        {
            x = (x * 1664525 + 1013904223) & (4194303);
            var y = d[x];
        }

        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        s.Reset();
        x = 1;
        s.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < loopLength; i++)
        {
            x = (x * 1664525 + 1013904223) & (4194303);
            var y = a[x];
        }

        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

x coefficients borrowed from Wikipedia's Linear congruential generator article

My results:

24390
 2076

That makes the array over 12x faster

Comment: This all makes perfect sense.

Comment: Your test is not really much better. You're also measuring `Random.Next`. You're also comparing apples and oranges. Using `array[7]` is something different than `dict[7]`. The former accesses the eighth element, the latter the value with the key 7.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I know, my attempt to remove it was to remove `randomTime`. It needed to be non sequential access to avoid caching/pipelining optimisations. Wasn't sure how else to get around it

Comment: @TimSchmelter, The apples and oranges is the whole point and where the speed improvement comes from, it's why the highest index was important instead of the count of elements. It wouldn't matter if it was a "GetElementWithKey(int key)" function the point is that we can use the array index as a key in this situation

Comment: Make the index that you access something like (i * bigPrime) & (smallestPowerOfTwoBelow5Million - 1). That should result in unpredictable accesses, take almost no time and still access almost the entire range.

Comment: Thanks @usr. that made a huge difference!

Comment: The new benchmark numbers show that the key calculation took about 75% of the time of the fast array version. Down from 8s to 2s. I actually was surprised to find the array only 3x faster. 12x is more like it and if you test a small array size such as 1024 you'll find even more difference because each access is in L1 cache.